# essential range of function,range and spectrum

Tags: measure-theory, spectral-theory

hi here $\sigma$ is spectrum,if $(X,\mu)$ is topological measure owed with borel measure and  $$
r_{ess}(f) = \{w \in \mathbb{R}_+ : \mu(f^{-1}(B(w, \epsilon))) > 0\}.
$$
i have proved that if f is continious and X is compact then $r_{ess}(f)=range(f)$

so if we assume  $H=L^{2}([0,1])$ and $f=C^{0}([0,1])$, X is compact how can we prove that $\sigma(M_{f})=range(f)$ where $M_{f}$ is multiplication operator  ,i showed that if $(\lambda-f)\phi$ is not invertible where $\phi \in L^{2}([0,1])$   then $\lambda$ must be in range(f) but i dont see how to do the converse i think the idea is to use that in this case i i use that $r_{ess}(f)=range(f)$
and last question what i dont assume that  neither $f=C^{0}([0,1])$ nor X is
compact $\sigma(f) $ would not be the \range(f) but why?
thanks

Comment: Well if $(X,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite then you have $\sigma(M_f)=r_{ess}(f)$. If $f$ is continous and $X$ compact. Then $M_f$ is the continuous functional calculus of $A: L^2(X; \mathbb{C})\rightarrow L^2(X,\mathbb{C}), f(t) \mapsto tf(t)$. That has spectrum $X$ i.e. $\sigma(A)=X$. By the properties of the continuous functional calculus you have $range(f)=f(X)=\sigma(f(A))=\sigma(M_f)=r_{ess}(f)$